# WAR file deployed but not accessible

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, war, tomcat-manager

In the image attached you can see ____WS and _____WSDevelop are my two web applications up and running.

I deployed a third .WAR called _____WSPrevRelease to maintain the previous version of my server code. However, the index.jsp on _____WSPrevRelease is not accessible. The logs don't show any errors after the .war deployment. The web application in even visible as a link on the manager UI (please refer the image) but clicking on it directs to a 'page not found'.

[Tomcat manager GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObPJf.png)

I have even deployed the same .WAR file on my local tomcat server where it runs perfectly fine.

Does anyone see any thing that I am missing here?  Is there some permissions, or tomcat settings that I am am missing? Thank you.

Here's my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>MyAppWS</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <description>JAX-RS Tools Generated - Do not modify</description>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>MyAppServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>MyAppServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        edu.myorg.myapp.model.InitServlet
    </servlet-class>        
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>    
  </servlet>  
  <filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Share your web.xml file please?

Comment: @TimoSta Sure, i've added the web.xml in the description